# Post Featured Image Display in front page

Tags: php, wordpress

I need help to display post featured image in my homepage in wordpress. I think I miss something.

```html
    <!-- POST FEATURE IMAGE-->
    <section id="project-features">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section-header">
                <h2>PORTFOLIO</h2>
                
                <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <!--feature image, if you not uploaded yet nothing happen-->
                                <?php 
                                    if(has_post_thumbnail()){
                                        the_post_thumbnail();
                                    }
                                ?>
                                <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>" alt="aaaa">
                            </div><!-- end col-->

                </div><!--end row-->

            </div><!--end section header-->
        </div><!-- end container-->
    </section><!--end project features-->
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, your question is very much off-topic. Please read: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). _"Questions **asking us to recommend or find** a book, tool, **software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_

Answer (score 0):

This should be simple. Enable post thumbnails in functions.php, read all of them on your frontpage.php, style them as needed and make permalinks to original posts where you have pictures loaded using WordPress media.

Comment: Thank you, I try to analyze it. actually im a newbie in wordpress. you answer is helpful

Comment: I'm glad that I helped :).

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. If you have knowledge on PHP and WordPress then you can create a loop of your post then you can simply add a permalink to your post detail and only print out the featured image on the post. You can also add a div on hover and print the post title on it.